# How do I protect my info from apps like CallApp?

Tags: account-security

It appears to me that apps like Whoscall and CallApp might access your photos and such. In case of a potential data breach/hacking in one of these apps - how can I delete my info from their servers?

Comment: Hahahahaha.In short you can't.You give someone some data you are at their mercy and governing law.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to request of them to delete my info from their server?

Answer (score 1):

If there was a breach then your information are likely no longer **only** at their server anymore and it is impossible to delete all copies. If you want to stop using these apps and want to make sure that your data are removed now (before a possible breach) you need to check this with the companies responsible for the apps since only these can remove the data. There is no universal way to remove private data from the web, no undo sharing data or similar.

Comment: Thank you. Judging by their app permissions, would you say they access one's gallery?

Comment: @SamuelP: Please see the section "About Permissions" in [Whoscall support](https://whoscall.com/en-US/support/faq/android/). To cite: *"Why did Whoscall need my storage (Photos/Media/Files) permission?
Storage permission is needed to allow users to send multimedia message (photos, files, video) through Whoscall."*

Comment: Yes, thanks. So using your judgement, would you say they store stuff from my gallery?

Comment: Also, I would appreciate your opinion on whether CallApp does that too.

Comment: @SamuelP: This is not a site where arbitrary proprietary closed source applications gets evaluated on what they do currently. The application can change its behavior anyway with the next update. Android provides mechanism to restrict what applications can do so please use these and simply don't allow the app to access the storage. And if you don't trust the app just don't use it

Comment: Thanks. I've already uninstalled the app but I'm afraid it might have stored something. What would you advise?

Comment: @SamuelP: As I said before: if you want to get your data removed you need to check this with the companies responsible for the apps since only these can remove the data. There is no universal unshare data. And I can neither see your past activity nor your past network traffic so I don't know if any sharing was done.

Comment: Thank you. They just sent me the following message, please tell me what this means. "Maybe when you downloaded whoscall offline data ,it will store in your SD card , it depends on your settings. This is why we need to access your SD card . But we WILL NOT store your data without authorization ! We can only acquire info that you agree (that is all about the app permissions)"

Comment: @SamuelP: This is not support for WhosCall. If you have questions on how to interpret their mail please ask the ones who wrote the mails. But it might be helpful to be more specific than "what does this whole mail mean"?

Comment: Thanks. A specific question. Take TrueCaller's privacy policy for example. It says "We transfer information to trusted vendors, service providers, and other partners who support our business and Services, such as providing technical infrastructure services, bug testing, analyzing how our Services are used, measuring the effectiveness of ads and services and facilitating payments as well as potential partners who may wish to work with us to provide other services."

Comment: Does this, then, mean they've already shared my info with these 3rd parties? If so, wouldn't I have to contact these 3rd parties?

Comment: @SamuelP: It does not say that they already have shared your specific information. It says that they might share these information in general. For information what was actually shared from your specific data you need to ask them.